# SPLUNK - show only some fields in the search

Tags: charts, splunk-query

I have 4 fields in logs file: index, userId, dateTime, name.
I want to show only 2 fields in the search for a given criterion, like this:

```
index="AAA" userId="user123" | chart dateTime, name by criterio1
```

But it gives error.
If it were in SQL it would be like this:

```
select dateTime, name where criterio1;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of chart, you need to use, search command

```
index="AAA" userId="user123" 
| search name = "criterio1"
| table userId, dateTime, name
```

or even better would be

```
index="AAA" userId="user123" "criterio1"
| table userId, dateTime, name
```

this would return all events where "criterio1" is present